# Reading JSON array with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I wrote a simple php script that will take in a JSON array (so I think), and it will add the received array into a MySQL database. However, when I call the script, it only adds the last item in the array to the database. Is there something simple here that I'm missing?

Also, my TRUNCATE TABLE fails to remove anything from the table.

```
<?php 
$handle = mysql_connect('localhost','root',''); 
if($handle==false) 
{ 
die('No database connection'); 
} 

$result = mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE 'available_ingredients'");


$db=mysql_select_db('r2bar2'); 
$query='INSERT INTO available_ingredients (drink_name) VALUES ("'.$_POST["drink_name"].'")'; 
$result=mysql_query($query); 
?>
```

EDIT:
Below is the code that generates the JSON array

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> j2 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
j2.add("drink_name", "rootbeer")
j2.add("drink_name", "pepsi")

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(my url);
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(j2));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())
```

Comment: Wide open to SQL injection attack.

Comment: Your TRUNCATE query is incorrect. Use ` (backtick) instead of ' (single quote) to quote your MySQL table and column names

Comment: Where are you getting the JSON?

Comment: It's being sent from an Android application using httppost.

Comment: Is the JSON you are trying to save stored in `$_POST["drink_name"]`?

Answer (score 0):

- `TRUNCATE TABLE` does not need or want single quotes around the table name
- You don't show us what `$_POST` contains exactly, so we can't say what happens exactly
- The code embeds user-supplied data inside SQL without sanitization, so it's vulnerable to SQL injection

You should get into the habit of checking all return values from the functions you call for errors (just like you already do with `mysql_connect`); this would cause you to discover why TRUNCATE TABLE fails immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Use json_decode to see how PHP is receiving the json object.  On the Android side, you should probably just make a single variable to send with your json data.

i.e. data='...json string goes here..'  (pseudo code as I'm not sure how you are doing it in android. The idea is that you would send 1 key/value to PHP, with the key being data, and the value being all the values of in your json string.)

Then in PHP, if you're sending via POST, then you can get it like this:

Note, Remove the truncate table query, as others have mentioned too it is wiping your entire table.

This code should answer your primary question though.

```
<?php
// decode json string
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);

// sanitize your input to avoid sql injection like others have mentioned
$safe_drink_name = mysql_real_escape_string($data->drink_name);

.... // your mysql connect code

$query='INSERT INTO available_ingredients (drink_name) VALUES ("'.$safe_drink_name.'")'; 
?>
```